# Handling different type JSON post requests in web api

Tags: c#, json, api, web

I have multiple Json entities in my solution. For example:

```
[DbName("school")]
public class School
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City{ get; set; }
}

[DbName("hospital")]
public class Hospital
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a web api which handles post requests. Requests come as JSON not string. I need to write a method where I will handle all requests and then I will decide the json type of the coming object like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CommonMethod(dynamic jsonObj)
{
    if(jsonObj.Type == "health")
        Hospital hospital = ConvertDynamicJson(jsonObj, hospital);
    else if(jsonObj.Type == "education")
        School school = ConvertDynamicJson(jsonObj, school);

    ...
}
```

I saw a lot of examples about dynamic json conversion but almost all of them use string json data.

Thanks

Comment: *Requests come as JSON not string*: Well, a JSON is a **string** with a special structure

Answer (score 1):

> Requests come as JSON not string

I assume that you are trying to tell the requests parsed by action selector and passed as object. It is not a string with Json formatted anymore.

Also, you can't determine a dynamic object like this way. Instead of trying to use dynamic objects, you could merge the models.

```
public class CommonActionInput
{
    public School School{ get; set; }

    public Hospital Hospital{ get; set; }
}
```

And you can determine which object is passed to the action.

```
ActionResult CommonMethod(CommonActionInput input)
{
    if(input.School != null)
    {

    }
    if(input.Hospital != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: School and hospital are always null. I have to declare these entities as json to be able to handle them in post method.

Comment: Yes, you should. Or create two seperate actions for entities.

Comment: How can I declare a class as Json into CommonActionInput class? Can you write your answer with more details please?